# Unable to inspect or click a toolbar button using AutoIt

Tags: windows, automation, autoit, oracleforms

I have an old app to automate using AutoIt.

My biggest problem is to access a specific button inside a toolbar (like the example message).
When inspecting, the inspector only shows the info of the toolbar, not the individual buttons. I can't inspect a specific element inside it.

How can I tell the script which button should be clicked? Maybe find the tool bar and tell to click button 3, but how? Is it possible like this?

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Toolbars are typically seen as one control with AutoIt, so would try an alternative concept. If the item is in the menu, then you could try using [WinMenuSelectItem](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinMenuSelectItem.htm). I see no code so [edit] to add code and details about the problem.

Comment: A lot of the time, these fancy buttons are located in the menu just above... So you can open Actions by sending Alt + a -- Send("!a")

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with the instance number of the button inside the toolbar.

Example: [CLASS:Viewcore_W32; INSTANCE:3]

I have to do some attempts with different indexes until right button is clicked but it works now.
Thanks.